# Trying to load a different iframe within a div popup box depending on which of several links is clicked to open the box

Tags: php, javascript

I have an overlay popup box (DIV + JavaScript + some CSS) which is toggled by a link, like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">
```

The box that pops up contains an iframe. Now I want different links on my page to load different iframes when the box opens; so that link A would toggle the box to appear, and load `iframe1.html` inside the box, while link B would toggle the same box to appear, but load `iframe2.html` inside the box, and so forth.

I'm a beginning programmer, and I first figured maybe this could be done with PHP, by putting something like this inside the popUpDiv:

```
<iframe src="http://mysite.com/iframe<?php echo $_GET ["iframeid"] ?>.html">
```

... and then simply adding `?iframeid=x` to each link's href, where `x` is the id of the iframe to be loaded.

This obviously won't work in practice though, because it requires a page reload, and when the link is clicked, the popUpDiv is toggled to open, but at the same instant, the page reloads, now with the `?iframeid=x` query string in place, but too late, since the popUpDiv disappeared on reload.

Is there perhaps a JavaScript equivalent that could be used, or can anybody suggest another way to make this work?

FYI, this is the kind of popup box I'm working with:
http://www.pat-burt.com/csspopup.html

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a really simple way of accomplishing this without additional JavaScripting, by simply using the `target` attribute:

```
<iframe name="myfavoriteiframe">
```

Then:

```
<a href="http://example.com/iframecontent.html" target="myfavoriteiframe" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">This is a link.</a>
```

P.S. Just FYI for any of those out there who might want to use this feature with Vimeo's JavaScript API, as I'm doing: In order to make API buttons work with this `target` method, it seems like the `iframe` `src`-attribute cannot be left blank. You need to specify a link to any of your videos in the `src`, so that a video loads into the iframe on page load, like this:

```
<iframe name="myfavoriteiframe" id="player_1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/[the_number_of_your_video]?api=1&amp;player_id=player_1">
```

I simply inserted the URL to the first video on my page, but you can use any of them, since they're hidden anyway.

Then link to any of your videos using the `target` method described above, and the pre-set `iframe` video will be replaced by a video of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Create two divs with the two variations of content (the two iframes with each specific URL). Then toggle by the name of the div.

```
<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv1')">
<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv2')">
```

Set the `id` attributes of the `div` elements appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only problem with this would be that I'd have to copy and paste a lot of code, since the div is made up of several nested divs, and repeat it, only difference being a different iframe in each instance. If I had any more than a handful of links, this would become messy.

Comment: Well you could create a template for this div code in question and parametrize it, then output it, e.g. either with PHP or with JS on the client side as JS is a precondition in your case. The popup method you're using looks pretty direct so you need to use it that direct. Or not at all, as your answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding something to the popup DIV element, I would add a required link to the `href` property of the link that you use to open the popup:

```
<a href="http://example.com/first/uri" onclick="pre_popup('popUpDiv')">
<a href="http://example.com/first/uri" onclick="pre_popup('popUpDiv')">
<a href="http://example.com/first/uri" onclick="pre_popup('popUpDiv')">
```

And then inside the `popup` function I would take the `href` parameter of the link that has triggered the event and use it in a popup:

```
function pre_popup(id) {
    // Take the href parameter of the link
    var href = this.href;

    // And then use it in the iframe
    window.frames["your_iframe"].src = href;

    // And then pop it
    popup(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't able to make this work, the href always loaded in the main window. But I figured out a much simpler way which I should have thought of right away. See my posted answer.